Cannot see "file,line,func" fields in the journal
I am trying to use sd_journal_print_with_location() function.
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>

int main() {
    sd_journal_print_with_location(LOG_INFO, "CODE_FILE=tst_file.c", "CODE_LINE=123", "main", "message");
    return 0;
}

And then execute:
$ gcc -o tst_file tst_file.c -lsystemd
$ ./tst_file
$ journalctl --identifier=tst_file
Dec 11 12:29:17 MYBOX tst_file[1827]: message

So the question is: Where are file, line, and func fields? Why cannot I see them with the journalctl?
What am I doing wrong?

Tried using --output=verbose or JSON output?

Ooops! Thanks @muru, the mystery is solved very easily...

journalctl needs an --output=verbose key to print all the fields to the stdout.
$ journalctl --identifier=tst_file --output=verbose

And the mystery is solved.
